# Is composite able to be rendered by command line?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes, command-line

Could composite be done by command line too?

Comment: Have you tried it? If you haven't then first try it and if the render is not identical, then you should ask "how to render with composition from command line?"

Comment: tried already. the command, blender -b .... -o //result_ -F PNG -a, works, but can't find any associations with compositing.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/52510/63966

Comment: Just run bpy.context.scene.render.use_compositing in console of blender then save it with Ctrl + S, now try rendering it from cmd.

Comment: @Yash hit `bpy.context.scene.render.use_compositing` in console, got True. but after running `./blender --background my_file.blend --composite-only \
    --render-result-from-file my_render_result.exr \
    --render-output my_file_output.exr`, not work, got `--composite-only': No such file or directory`

Comment: Don't run this long command in cmd, just run the standard render command that you previously used

Comment: @Yash tried two ways. 1. open the test file, run the script in the console, then run command in terminal. 2. save the script as a py file, run same command followed by -P script.py. Unfortunately, neither of them didn't do compositing, just a normal picture rendering.

Comment: Why did you save the script as py, you just have to save the blend file after running the command in the console  x(